# Como colocar mat-chips dentro de um textarea

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou usando o [Material Chips Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) em conjunto com um textarea. Gostaria de colocar minha lista de Chips dentro do meu textarea.

Atualmente funciona da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de ter algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu codigo atual:

```
   <div class="col-xl-3">
      <textarea class="form-control"
         #inputContasB2W
         (keyup.enter)="adicionaConta()"
         [formControl]="contasB2WControl"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      </textarea>

      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption="true" #auto="matAutocomplete">
         <mat-option (click)="adicionaConta()" *ngFor="let contaB2W of 
         contasFiltradas | async" [value]="contaB2W">
            {{contaB2W}}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>

   </div>

   <div class="col-xl-2">
       <mat-chip-list>
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let contaB2W of contasAdicionadasB2W; let j = index"
            selectable="false"
            removable="true"
            (removed)="removeTag(j)">
            {{contaB2W}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove><i class="fa fa-close"></i></mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
       </mat-chip-list>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Experimente colocar um `event.stopPropagation();` na sua function `adicionaConta($event)`

Comment: Qual seria a função do event.stopPropagation ali? Eu acho que essa é mais uma questão de template do que TS